# i am getting some exception to start workflow on an item of a list

Tags: 2010, workflow

My Code which I am using is given below Which throws an exception -

> ServerException was caught - itemGuid

What I want to do is very simple, from the list, i have multiple items for which I have to start workflow.
WorkFLows are defined not for all list but for content type of Instruction.
I am able to get the workflow associations for those content type. Is there any other alternative ? to start workflow

```
Web oWeb = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(oWeb);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            ListCollection docListss = ctx.Web.Lists;
            ctx.Load(docListss);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            ContentTypeCollection contntTypes = docListss.GetByTitle("original documents").ContentTypes;
            ctx.Load(contntTypes);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            var woffirst = contntTypes;
            WorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection = null;
            foreach (ContentType typ in contntTypes)
            {
                if (typ.Name == "Instruction")
                {
                    ctx.Load(typ.WorkflowAssociations);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    associationCollection = typ.WorkflowAssociations;
                }
            }
            List docList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("original documents");
            var query = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>"
            };

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItemCollection = docList.GetItems(query);
            ctx.Load(listItemCollection);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            Guid lsttogo = listItemCollection.Where(x => Convert.ToString(x.FieldValues["Title"]) == docTitle).Select(y => new Guid(Convert.ToString(y.FieldValues["UniqueId"]))).First();

            var wfServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(ctx, ctx.Web);

            var interopService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowInteropService();
            ctx.Load(docList);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            Guid listid = docList.Id;

            var param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (WorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection)
            {
                if (association.Name == "3. Validate minor version")
                {
                    association.AutoStartChange = true;
                    association.AutoStartCreate = false;
                    association.AssociationData = string.Empty;
                    var lid = association.ListId;

                    interopService.StartWorkflow(association.Name, association.Id, listid, lsttogo, param);

                }
            }
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```